How to automatically detect the sign of the slope in a time series with serrated shape in R?
I have a time series that looks like a jagged shape. I want to know the positive or negative slope of the jagged depression. Sometimes the noise in this time series can be heavy, so it is difficult to clearly see the positive or negative. I used a simple linear fitting to calculate the global slope and rregard it with the positive or negative slope. However, it is obvious that many times this did not work. Thank you. One example of the data in R is attached as follows, thank you.
aa <-c(seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10),seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10),seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10),
       seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10),seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10),seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10))

bb <- scale(aa)+0.5*rnorm(length(aa))

To be specific, I would like know if the sign of the slope of the parts (created by seq(1,50,1)) is positive or negative. Thanks
this is the code in R that I used to take its sign by simply using linear fitting,
t <- seq(1,length(aa),1)
v <- lm(bb~t,na.action=na.omit)
v_sign <- v$coefficients[2]

This did not work in many cases, therefore I would like to see any suggestions or help from the community to help resolve this issue. Thanks

One approach could be to extract the trend using a moving average or a loess curve, and take the slope of that. e.g. it looks like we get a pretty good cleaned version of the trend using library(ggplot2); ggplot(data.frame(t,bb), aes(t,bb)) + geom_smooth(span = 0.1)

Why not use a piecewise regression method.

As mentioned in the comments, piecewise linear regression is one option. I'm sure there are libraries for this, but here's a basic implementation. I don't know if you intend to pass this on to some automated analysis or not, but I figured a plot wouldn't hurt.
set.seed(1)
aa <- c(seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10),seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10),seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10),
       seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10),seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10),seq(1,50,1),seq(51,5,-10))
bb <- scale(aa)+0.5*rnorm(length(aa))
tt <- seq(1,length(aa),1)

dtf <- data.frame(tt, bb)
nrdtf <- nrow(dtf)

l <- 20  #pice length
so <- 5  #stepover

lh <- l %/% 2
sta <- seq(1, to=nrdtf, by=so)
sto <- sta+l
ix <- cbind(sta, sto)[sto < nrdtf,]

coefs <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrdtf, ncol=3)

for ( i in seq_len(nrow(ix)) ) {
    stai <- ix[i, 1]
    stoi <- ix[i, 2]
    dtfi <- dtf[stai:stoi,]
    modi <- lm(bb ~ tt, data=dtfi)
    rsqi <- summary(modi)$r.squared
    coefs[stai+lh, ] <- c(modi$coefficients, rsqi)
}

par(mar=c(2, 2, 1, 1))
plot(dtf$tt, dtf$bb, type="l")
size <- 5*coefs[, 3]/max(coefs[, 3], na.rm=TRUE)
points(dtf$tt, rep_len(min(dtf$bb), nrdtf), pch=16,
  col=c("#ff000033", "#00ff0033")[(coefs[, 2] > 0) + 1], cex=size)


Green for positive slope, red for negative slope, size reflects R-squared goodness of fit.
